# how to set focus on textfield when an combobox item is selected

Tags: java

```
private void cbdmnstatItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getsource()==getSelectedItem){
        tf1.setFocus(true);
    }        
}
```

Comment: You should also add a question to the body of your **question**.

Comment: does your code compile? please describe your problem and solution strategy a bit better.

Comment: brother i am new to java actually i am will to set focus on a textfield when any combobox item is clicked...!! can i receive some help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to set the focus on your textfield.

[javax.swing.JComponent#requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29)

In your case it would look like:

```
private void onStateChange(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    tf1.requestFocus();
}
```

**UPDATE**
This will work for you, if your textfields and combobox-items are static, if they are dynamic it is getting a bit more complicated.

```
 private void onStateChange(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        Object selectedItem = evt.getItem();
        if (selectedItem.equals("X")) {
            jTextField1.requestFocus();
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("Y")) {
            jTextField2.requestFocus();
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("Z")) {
            jTextField3.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i'm glad i could help you, please mark this question as answered then :)

Comment: but what if we have a,b,c textfields and x,y,z items in combobox and when we select x item, focus is set on textfield a & when we select y item, focus is set on b textfield; and when we select z item, focus is set on c textfield????? ny idea brother???

Comment: i'll update my answer .. just give me a few mins

Comment: i selected on the tick mark hope it is marked as answered right??

Comment: yeah .. this was the way to go ... i already updated my answer .. i hope this is what you was looking for

Comment: no problem .. that's what this community is for ;D also you marked the other answer as answered instead of this one. would be nice if you could change it back, since this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should something like this (a quick-dirty example):

```
public class TestApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            Container pane = f.getContentPane();
            final JTextField field = new JTextField();
            pane.add(field);
            pane.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            JComboBox b = new JComboBox();
            b.addItem("Don't focus");
            b.addItem("Focus");
            b.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        if("Focus".equals(e.getItem())) {
                            field.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            pane.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```